# Precompiling Express EJS templated pages

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way to precompile pages made with node.js express.js and ejs? Most of the interactive site we are building will be displaying static content. I built the templating engine as a way to make it easier to develop and manage the site, but since it's displaying static content there will be no need for the production to be rendered server-side.